# aplicar formula de una clase a un input en python

Tags: python, diseño-de-clases

He creado una clase, y dentro de esa clase he definido una formula para calcular el dni que se introduzca por teclado. Pero a la hora de aplicar esa formula no se exactamente como hacerlo, he intentado varias formas pero me da errores. A ver si alguien me ayuda, por favor.

```
class DatosPersonales:
    
    def __init__(self,nombre,apellidos,nif,poblacion,pais):
        self.nombre=nombre.capitalize()
        self.apellidos=apellidos.title()
        self.nif=nif
        self.poblacion=poblacion.capitalize()
        self.pais=pais.upper()
        
    def dni(self):
        while(True):
            tabla = "TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE"
            numeros = "1234567890"
            nif = input("Introduce tu NIF: ")
            if len(nif) == 9:
                letra = nif[8].upper()
                dni = nif[:8]
                if (len(dni) == len( [n for n in dni if n in numeros])):
                    if tabla[int(dni)%23] == letra:
                        print("El NIF introducido es correcto")
                        break    
            else:
                print("El NIF introducido es incorrecto")  
    
    def __str__(self):
        return"{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}".format(self.nombre,self.apellidos,self.nif,self.poblacion,self.pais)
    

nombre=input("Introduce tu nombre: ")
apellidos=input("Introduce tus apellidos: ")
nif=input("Introduce tu NIF: ")
poblacion=input("En que poblacion resides: ")  
pais=input("Pais: ")   


respuesta=DatosPersonales(nombre,apellidos,nif,poblacion,pais)

print(respuesta)
```

Answer (score 0):

El método `dni` no guarda relación con la clase `DatosPersonales`. Si te fijas, dentro de ese método no se ocupa el parámetro `self`; eso es señal de que no hay conexión entre el método y la clase.

Tampoco es un método de clase; es un simple método y corresponde extraerlo de la clase, quedando así:

```
class DatosPersonales:

    def __init__(self, nombre, apellidos, nif, poblacion, pais):
        self.nombre = nombre.capitalize()
        self.apellidos = apellidos.title()
        self.nif = nif
        self.poblacion = poblacion.capitalize()
        self.pais = pais.upper()

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}".format(self.nombre, self.apellidos, self.nif, self.poblacion, self.pais)


def dni():
    while (True):
        tabla = "TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE"
        numeros = "1234567890"
        nif = input("Introduce tu NIF: ")
        if len(nif) == 9:
            letra = nif[8].upper()
            dni = nif[:8]
            if (len(dni) == len([n for n in dni if n in numeros])):
                if tabla[int(dni) % 23] == letra:
                    print("El NIF introducido es correcto")
                    break
        else:
            print("El NIF introducido es incorrecto")
    return dni
```

Sólo hubo que eliminar el parámetro `self` y correr todo el método hacia el margen izquierdo.

El único cambio en el resto del código es llamar a `dni()` para pedir el `nif`:

```
nombre = input("Introduce tu nombre: ")
apellidos = input("Introduce tus apellidos: ")
nif = dni()
poblacion = input("En que poblacion resides: ")
pais = input("Pais: ")

respuesta = DatosPersonales(nombre, apellidos, nif, poblacion, pais)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Candid Moe. Saco el metodo dni de la clase y funciona. De todas formas, no se podria meter dentro de la clase?

Answer (score 0):

En la clase pides el nif hasta que sea válido, con lo que sería el mejor sitio para solicitarlo.

Siendo así el método `dni()` no necesita ningún parámetro y puedes envolverlo en `@staticmethod`.

Podría quedar así:

```
class DatosPersonales:

    def __init__(self, nombre, apellidos, poblacion, pais):
        self.nombre = nombre.capitalize()
        self.apellidos = apellidos.title()
        #   self.nif = nif
        self.poblacion = poblacion.capitalize()
        self.pais = pais.upper()
        self.nif = self.dni()

    @staticmethod
    def dni():
        while (True):
            tabla = "TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE"
            numeros = "1234567890"
            nif = input("Introduce tu NIF: ")
            if len(nif) == 9:
                letra = nif[8].upper()
                dni = nif[:8]
                if (len(dni) == len([n for n in dni if n in numeros])):
                    if tabla[int(dni) % 23] == letra:
                        print("El NIF introducido es correcto")                        
                        return nif
            else:
                print("El NIF introducido es incorrecto")

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}".format(self.nombre, self.apellidos, self.nif, self.poblacion, self.pais)
```

Al crear el objeto se elimina el parámetro `nif`, realizas la llamada desde el `__init__` de la clase.

```
nombre = 'Pepe'
apellidos = 'Fernandez'
#   nif = input("Introduce tu NIF: ")
poblacion = 'Gijón'
pais = 'España'

# noinspection PyArgumentList
respuesta = DatosPersonales(nombre, apellidos, poblacion, pais)

print(respuesta)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @TomyGijon